# potentially dangerous Request servicestack

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, servicestack

I am submitting a query string that contains a value 
 `Body=%3Ch2%3E (Body=<h1>)` 
to a servicestack rest endpoint. That results in:

> A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (Body=\"<h2>\").

I know that in MVC 4 you can allow Html content for an specific field, if you decorate the field in the model with [AllowHtml] like so:

> [AllowHtml]
>   public string Body { get; set; }

Did that, but the error persists. Had doubts that it was service stack not partaking properly in the validation process, so tested by creating a pure MVC 4 controller with the same model, and that works fine.

However I need a solution for ServiceStack. Their documentation is thin and Google searches lead nowhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you are hosting your ServiceStack service inside an ASP.NET application.

You could add the following to the `<system.web>` section of your web.config file in order to disable request validation for the entire application:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    ...
</system.web>
```

And if you want to disable request validation only for a particular endpoint and not the entire application use the `<location>` tag in your web.config:

```
<location path="hello">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    </system.web>
</location>
```

This will disable request validation for all `/hello` endpoints in your application. For example `/hello?Body=%3Ch2%3E` will work but `/bar?Body=%3Ch2%3E` won't work.

You can read more about request validation in ASP.NET in the [`following MSDN article`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339.aspx).

And obviously you should not be worried about this if you are self-hosting your ServiceStack service.

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping for a solution which would be similar to the one for pure MVC (an attribute or smth), but I suppose that's not likely to be happen. At least I can limit it to a the endpoint in question.

Comment: That's only a limitation/feature of ASP.NET. As I said if you self-host your ServiceStack service you will not get this error. I guess that the authors of ServcieStack didn't want to introduce ASP.NET specific attributes for the request dtos because that would tie them to ASP.NET. Furthermore, ASP.NET allows you to disable request validation for certain endpoints as shown in my answer.